# Result of value comparison in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

In the following piece of code the output is 1 but I'm not sure why. Has i been implicitly changed to a boolean? How can an integer value be set to an expression like this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, i = 1;
  i = b < a < c;
  cout << i;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a not-so-secret fact that "boolean" values are just `0` and `1`.

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) Because the C++ standard says so. P.S. What do you think "`b < a < c`" does? If you think that it checks if `a` is between `b` and `c`, you'd be wrong, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What would you expect `i` to be?  Please explain why you think that as well.

Comment: By the [C++ precedence and associativity rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the expression on the right parses as `(b < a) < c`. Step by step, `b < a` evaluates to `false` which has an integer value of `0`, then `0 < c` evaluates to `true` which has an integer value of `1`. So in the end the assignment reduces to `i = 1;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has `i` been implicitly changed to a boolean?

No. Rather, a boolean expression has been implicitly converted to `int`, then stored in `i`, as commented by @WhozCraig.

> How can an integer value be set to an expression like this?

Because it follows the C++ Standard.

---

When you do:

```
i = b < a < c;
```

since the first `<` and the second `<` have the same operator precedence (since they are the same operator), so:

> Operators that have the same precedence are bound to their arguments
> in the direction of their associativity. For example, the expression a
> = b = c is parsed as a = (b = c), and not as (a = b) = c because of right-to-left associativity of assignment, *but a + b - c is parsed (a > + b) - c and not a + (b - c) because of left-to-right associativity of addition and subtraction.*

as mentioned in [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), which means that this expression of yours will be parsed as if it was written like this:

```
i = (b < a) < c;
```

which will evaluate the condition inside the parentheses, which is False.

Now `bool` to `int` conversion is implicit:

§4.7/4 from the C++ Standard says (Integral Conversion)

> If the source type is bool, the value **`false`** is converted to zero and the value **`true`** is converted to one.

which means that false will be converted to 0, and then we basically end up doing:

```
i = 0 < c;
```

which evaluates to true, since `c` is equal to 1. Now `i` is of type `int`, which means that another, second implicit conversion from boolean to integer takes place, eventually assigning 1 to `i`.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't downvote this. Dunno who did. I will, however, uptick it now that it's fixed.